# Find the Fourier series of $x-x^2 , f(x+2π)=f(x)$

Tags: fourier-series

Find a Fourier series to represent $x−x^2$
from $x=−π$
to $x=π$
using complex Fourier series.

I got $C0$ = $-π^2/3$
I am getting $Cn$=$π^2/n^2 + π/in^2 + π^2/2in - π/2n^2 $

After simplification I am getting i in numerator. Kindly help.

Comment: This is not a site for homework, you have to try before asking and show what you have tried.

Comment: I am stuck with the last step of the integration , I am getting i in numerator. I can't cancel it .

Comment: Then write down what your problem is so we can help

Comment: I have edited , kindly help @julio_es_sui_glace

Comment: Is $i$ the complex number $i$? Without working through the whole problem and guessing what you might have done wrong, how can we know where $i$ came from? You will have to show what you did.

Comment: My steps are too big and I don't know how to input all those in math language here , so I added my last step and one of the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us compute these desired coefficients. We set $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ to be the $2\pi$-periodic function such that for $x \in ]-\pi,\pi], \, f(x) = x-x^2$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^*$,
$$\begin{align*}
2\pi \cdot c_n(f) 
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-inx}(x-x^2) dx 
= \frac{i}{n}\left[ e^{-inx}(x-x^2)\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \frac{i}{n} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-inx}(1-2x) dx \\
&= \frac{i}{n}(-1)^n (\pi-\pi^2 -(-\pi-\pi^2)) \\
&-\left( \frac{i^2}{n^2} (-1)^n \left[ e^{-inx}(1-2x)\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} 
 \frac{i^2}{n^2} - \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-inx}\cdot (-2) dx\right)\\
&= (-1)^n\frac{2i\pi}{n} + (-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2} (1-2\pi -(1+2\pi)) + 0 \\
&= 2\pi (-1)^n\left( -\frac{2}{n^2} + \frac{i}{n} \right)
\end{align*}$$

So
$$c_n(f) = -(-1)^n\frac{2}{n^2} + (-1)^n\frac{i}{n}$$

Now $c_0(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (x-x^2) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\frac{x^2}{2} -  \frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{\pi^2}{2} - \frac{\pi^3}{3} - (\frac{\pi^2}{2} + \frac{\pi^3}{3})\right) = -\frac{\pi^3}{3} $

Since $c_{-n} = \bar{c_n}$, this gives us
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} c_n e^{inx} \\
&= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{-n} e^{-inx}\\
&= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \overline{c_{n} e^{inx}} \\
&= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{inx} + \overline{c_{n} e^{inx}} \\
&= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2 \Re(c_n e^{inx}) \\
&= c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx) 
\end{align*}$$
where $a_n = 2 \Re(c_n) = -(-1)^n\frac{4}{n^2}$ and $b_n = -2\Im(c_n) = -(-1)^n\frac{2}{n}$.

Comment: Why are we taking limit from 0 to 2π , the gave x=-π to x=π .

Comment: Oh sorry did not read well let me adjust

Comment: @SashwathKumar Here you go

Comment: I get the integration steps , but when applying the limits, the value changes when n=1,3,5 (odd number) and when n is even we get the negative value of the latter , so Cn will change right ?  @julio_es_sui_glace

Comment: @SashwathKumar Edit: sign error; please check correction in 5 mn

Comment: Also note that evaluating in zero gives you $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^3}{12}$.

Comment: When we apply the limits . π and -π , $e^(-inx) $ becomes -1 when n=1,3,5,7...   When n=2,4,6,8 it becomes 1 . So $Cn$ becomes $1/in + 2/n^2 $ for n=1,3,5,.. and it becomes $-1/in -2/n^2 $ for n=2,4,6... Right @julio_es_sui_glace

Comment: @SashwathKumar Yes I noticed, I corrected it one hour ago, check my comments

Comment: If you need to check results, use https://www.symbolab.com/solver/fourier-series-calculator